# Creating a list by adding items when conditions are met

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Connector
{
    public double Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Len { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Count { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of such facilities:

```
List<Connector> resutsList = new List<Connector>();
```

Below is an example of the contents of such a list:

```
1 | IZO | 1000 | 200 | 2
2 | IZO | 1000 | 200 | 4
3 | IZO | 600  | 200 | 5
4 | IZO | 1000 | 200 | 2
5 | IZO | 600  | 180 | 7
6 | IZO | 600  | 180 | 3
```

I need such a result: (This is the sum of the Count positions when the Len and Height conditions are met.)

```
1 | IZO | 1000 | 200 | 8
2 | IZO | 600  | 200 | 5
3 | IZO | 600  | 180 | 10
```

Is it possible to do any Linq combination?

Or another simple solution?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. And to the next question “how?” do a grouping of the data and sum them up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is group your list by `Name`, `Len` & `Height`, which you can do using the LINQ [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) method.

Then, you want to project that group to a new object using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) and a [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Double__) aggregation on the `Count` property. For example:

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Len, x.Height })
    .Select(x => new {  x.Key.Name, x.Key.Len, x.Key.Height, Count = x.Sum(y => y.Count) })
    .ToList();
```

As for the ID - well it makes a limited amount of sense in an aggregate operation. You have basically 2 choices

1. Use an incrementing number as one of the other answers does

   ```
   .Select( (x,i) => new { ID = i, ....
   ```
2. That the first ID from the group

   ```
   .Select(x => new {  ID = x.First().ID, ....
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my effort.

```
class Program
{
    public class Connector
    {
        public Connector(double id, string name, double len, double height, double count)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Len = len;
            Height = height;
            Count = count;
        }

        public double Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Len { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Count { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var l = new List<Connector>
        {
            new Connector(1, "IZO", 1000, 200, 2),
            new Connector(2, "IZO", 1000, 200, 4),
            new Connector(3, "IZO", 600, 200, 5),
            new Connector(4, "IZO", 1000, 200, 2),
            new Connector(5, "IZO", 600, 180, 7),
            new Connector(6, "IZO", 600, 180, 3)
        };

        var sums = from c in l
                   group c by new { c.Name, c.Len, c.Height } into g
                   select new { g.First().Id, g.Key.Name, g.Key.Len, g.Key.Height, Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) };

    }
}
```

```
[image]

Please note that the ids are not exactly like in your example. (1,2,3 vs 1,3,5)

I don't believe you can get the index with query expression syntax, but here is another Linq way to do it and get the desired indexes:

```
            var sums = l.GroupBy(c => new { c.Name, c.Len, c.Height })
            .Select((g, index) => new{
                Id = index+1,
                g.Key.Name,
                g.Key.Len,
                g.Key.Height,
                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
            });
```

Please note the `index + 1`

[image]

Comment: Great answer but you don't say explain what you did or why you did it this wa.

Comment: @tymtam great answer +1 for the indexing

Answer (score 0):

you can try is

> Here we group the elements of resultList  by three conditions `Name,Len,Height`.Then we create a new Connector object from that group by by using the `Len,Height,Name,& Id` then we `Sum` all the elements present in that group and assign `Count` var with the `Sum`.

```
var List =  from result in resultList
            group d by new { d.Name, d.Len , d.Height} into g
            select new Connector
            (
                Id = g.First().ID,
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Len = g.Key.Len,
                Height = g.Key.Height,
                count = g.Sum(s => s.Count)
            );
```

Note:- this will not generate incrementing ID if you want that you may refer @tymtam's answer

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: This creates a list with ids 1,3,5; not 1,2,3 :) Please see my answer for a 1,2,3 answer :)

Comment: @tymtam great answer sir  will modify my answer with your suggestion too